# Sort javascript array of objects by property value and reorder by condition

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object

I have an array of objects Like :

```js
    var newArray = [
      {value : "P1"},
      {value : "P2/S2"},
      {value : "P2"},
      {value : "P1"},
      {value : "P1/S2"},
      {value : "P1/S3"},
      {value : "P2/S1"},
      {value : "P1/S3"},
      {value : "P2/S2"},
      {value : "P1"},
      {value : "P2"},
      {value : "P3"}
    ];
    
    function compare( a, b ) {
      if ( a.value < b.value ){
        return -1;
      }
      if ( a.value > b.value ){
        return 1;
      }
      return 0;
    }
    
    newArray.sort( compare );
    console.log(newArray);
```

> [{"value":"P1"},{"value":"P1"},{"value":"P1"},{"value":"P1/S2"},{"value":"P1/S3"},{"value":"P1/S3"},{"value":"P2"},{"value":"P2"},{"value":"P2/S1"},{"value":"P2/S2"},{"value":"P2/S2"},{"value":"P3"}]

But here i have a rearrangement in sorting if there is no S value after P value. P value should be low priority if there is no S value. I am expecting a result like this :

> [{"value":"P1/S2"},{"value":"P1/S3"},{"value":"P1/S3"},{"value":"P1"},{"value":"P1"},{"value":"P1"},{"value":"P2/S1"},{"value":"P2/S2"},{"value":"P2/S2"},{"value":"P2"},{"value":"P2"},{"value":"P3"}]

Answer (score 3):

You could add a suffix and sort smaller strings to the bottom.

```js
function compare({ value: a }, { value: b }) {
    a += 'ZZZ';
    b += 'ZZZ';
    return a > b || -(a < b);
}

var array = [{ value: "P1" }, { value: "P2/S2" }, { value: "P2" }, { value: "P1" }, { value: "P1/S2" }, { value: "P1/S3" }, { value: "P2/S1" }, { value: "P1/S3" }, { value: "P2/S2" }, { value: "P1" }, { value: "P2" }, { value: "P3" }];
   
array.sort(compare);

console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe computing values weight? For example:

```
function computeWeight(str) {
  var weight = 0;
  for (var i = str.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
    weight = weight + (str.charCodeAt(i) * Math.pow(10, i));
  }
  return weight;
}
```

this way longer strings will have a greater weight than the smaller ones because they have more symbols. Then you can use that function in your `compare`.